# Bridging Wireless interface on Linux

Tags: networking, virtualization, wireless-bridge

Someone told they actually bridged a wifi interface on Linux, others says this is not possible.

I would like to bridge a virtual-machine (kvm+qemu) interface to the host wifi network, is this possible? (I already tried the standard way with bridging tools without success)

My wifi card model is:

`03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)`

and I am using the `iwlwifi-?.ucode` firmware (? stands for I don't know exactly which one).

---

So now I wonder which is the truth,
may I use some sort of black-magic to bridge my wifi interface or is this impossible ? And why ? If I change the wireless card would this be possible?

I'm looking for a detailed answer to this question, tips to where to find it are really appreciated.

---

UPDATE:
Even more strange, I can actually bridge a lxc container, but if I try to manually setup a bridged interface:

```
$ ip link add name br0 type bridge
$ ip link set wlp3s0 master br0
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
```

and in `/etc/network/interface`

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 172.20.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_maxwait 5
    post-up /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp3s0 -j MASQUERADE
    post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    post-down /sbin/iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wlp3s0 -j MASQUERADE
```